# Best practice to execute ruby-script using rails-data as a cronjob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to create a ruby-script which is triggered at certain times of the day. This script needs to use data from the rails-app like the session-data or the database.

Also the script needs like 10 minutes to execute if that's a problem (in php, it is).

What's the best/easiest/cleanest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have a look at [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) OR [Rufus Schedular](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler).

Comment: you can also use https://github.com/javan/whenever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a model that handles everything. For example:

```
class PaymentProcessor
  def self.daily
    # whatever needs to be done.
  end
end
```

Run that code from cron with:

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/runner "PaymentProcessor.daily" > tmp/payment.log
```

Benefits for this solution: You have full access to all Rails methods. The code is in the same code base (version control) than the whole app. Furthermore the code can be tested with the same way than every other code in your app. On the other hand cron is a well understood giant. You can use gems like Whenever to define the cron tab with a nice DSL in Ruby.

Comment: This looks like a clean and nice solution. I will use it with whenever. What is a DSL?

Comment: DSL means domain-specific language, in this case a way to describe cron tasks in a nice ruby syntax: `every 2.days, :at => '3:15 pm' {...}` reads nicer than `15 15 */2 * *`.

Comment: Ah thanks. Can I somehow also use data from the ApplicationController inside the model?

Comment: Not with the above code, perhaps with some other technic. But it sounds weird to me when a cron task needs something only a controller can provide. Why do you think you need your controller with cron? Can you explain what you want to achieve?